# What's the synonymous of "proper distance" here?

Tags: general-relativity, space-expansion

In John Gribbin's Ten Tantalizing Truths, the author discusses the proper distance:-

> Imagine that you are standing somewhere in the middle of one of those long travelling walkways found in places such as airports, but the travellator has not been switched on. Mark the spot where you are standing with a blob of paint. I am standing at the end of the travellator, and when it is turned on the pavement starts to carry you away from me. But you walk briskly towards me, overcoming the speed of the walkway, and when you get to me, the travellator is turned off. By that time, the blob of paint is much farther away from me than it was when you set out. That is **the ‘proper distance’** to the paint blob now, not the distance it was from me when you started walking. In order to calculate the proper distance to an object by measuring the redshift in the light from it, we need to use some very simple equations.

What's the synonymous of "proper distance" here? Can it be "own distance" like "proper time" = "own time", or it's closer to "actual distance"?